# Ruby: Convert memory address string format to bytes for shellcode

Tags: ruby, shell, exploit

I have found a program that leaks the address of it's buffer. I can capture that by sending a socket.get_once but it's in a string format. So when I go to pass it to pack it doesn't want a string value. How can I convert a memory address in string format to an address that I can put in shellcode?

Example Address captured: 0x7fffffffdfc0

Using string.pack('Q') it throws an error that it's not an integer. So I tried using a loop to break up the sections into pairs like so:

string.scan(/../).reverse_each { |x| buf += [x.to_i].pack('S')}

I know this is probably a simple solution but for some reason I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

It was easy...

buf += [string.to_i(16)].pack('Q')